# Merge unrelated tables response in api - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to merge 2 unrelated tables results into unified response.

```
$facebook = DB::table('facebook')->select('message','permalink_url','full_picture','created_time','shares','comments','reactions',DB::raw('SUM(shares+comments+reactions) as engagement'))
        ->groupBy('message','permalink_url','full_picture','created_time','shares','comments','reactions')->get();

$instagram = DB::table('instagram')
        ->select('created_time','caption','media_url','thumbnail','comments','likes','video_views',DB::raw('SUM(comments+likes+video_views) as engagement'))
        ->groupBy('created_time','caption','media_url','thumbnail','comments','likes','video_views')->get();

$merged = $instagram->merge($facebook);
$result = $merged->all();
return $result;
```

Since both tables fields are different. I want to merge into generic response. For example **message** from facebook table and **caption** from instagram table should be as **text** key in response. Same for other fields. How I can do this? toArray?

In nutshell, there should be one generic key for both tables in response.

Comment: Sounds like a polymorphic model might be in order.

Comment: You may use collect() to merge them